# Re-submit App to Applestore

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

My app did not get rejected but I honestly forgot a button that will give any player unlimited amount of gold. I was supposed to hide it before submitting but I forgot.
Does anyone know how to pull that app back and re-submit it before they evaluate ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about iTunes connect customer support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can log into iTunes connect and reject your binary. Fix your button and resubmit. You will be placed at the end of the review queue, but you can at least fix the button.

Comment: Thanks Douglas... Finally found the reject binary button. I worked very hard on that app for people to just get gold like that... lol

Comment: What's the name of your App?  I will look for it!  Also, could you check the accept button?  Thanks!  It would be bad if users got all that gold. I know how hard I work on my apps!

Comment: name of the app is iBrains II. You can search for Farini in app store but i think it will take a week for them to approve. I accepted your answer but the question was held "off-topic"

Comment: Thanks, and at least you got your answer.  I will look for the App!  Happy Coding, love the website by the way!